# How to start auto increment for each new user that signs-up

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rdbms

I am building real-time messaging web app using PHP, AJAX jQuery, JavaScript, MySQL. So I have set auto-increment (message_id: BIG INT) for each message, Also displaying them using message_id. My question is: The message_id should start from 1 for each user that signs-up. Also should (message_id and Email) both be my primary key?
Is that possible or is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
CREATE TABLE message (
  message_id BIGINT,
  Email INT,
  message char(200),
  primary key (message_id, Email)
);
```

Comment: So What Do You Need For Email?

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLE message1 (
  message_id BIGINT,
  Email  char(200),
  message char(200),
  primary key (message_id, Email)
);
```

Comment: That is backwards.  And it only works for `ENGINE=MyISAM`.  And it is missing `AUTO_INCREMENT`.